# Is the formula $\neg\neg\forall x (\neg P(x) \,\vee\, \neg\neg P(x))$ provable in intuitionistic logic?

Tags: constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

I understand that in propositional logic, $\neg\neg Q$ is intuitionistically provable whenever $Q$ is classically provable, but here there is a universal quantifier complicating things.

Comment: I don't know what *intuitionistic logic* entails.  However, (informally) $\neg \neg P(x)$ is logically equivalent to $P(x)$.  Also, $\neg \neg \forall x \cdots$ is logically equivalent to $\forall x \cdots.$  Finally, given any variable $x$, and any statement $P(x)$, either the statement is true or it is false.  Therefore $\forall x, \{ ~P(x) \vee [\neg P(x)] ~\}.$

Comment: @user2661923: Intuitionistic logic is (somewhat simplified, perhaps) the logic used to do constructive proofs. In this logic, statements such as $P\vee\neg P$ and $\neg\neg P \to P$ are not valid in general.

Comment: BTW you are referencing Glivenko’s Theorem

Comment: Informally, if it were provable, I'd expect $\lnot\lnot\forall p:\Omega(\lnot p \lor \lnot\lnot p)$ to follow in a general topos.  But in the topos of sheaves on $\mathbb{R}$, if you consider global sections of $\Omega$ given by $(a, \infty)$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\lnot p$ evaluates to $(-\infty, a)$, $\lnot\lnot p$ evaluates to $(a, \infty)$, and so $\forall p:\Omega(\lnot p \lor \lnot\lnot p)$ would evaluate to false; and therefore its double negation would also evaluate to false.

Comment: Also the predicate version of Glivenko's theorem won't help because if you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-negation_translation you can see that the expression isn't in the image of the Gödel–Gentzen translation (nothing with a $\lor$ is).  There's other versions mentioned in the article, like Kuroda's, but they seem to not apply either.

Comment: @user2661923 you have pretty much summed up the things that actually do not work in general in intuitionistic logic! More concretely; in intuitionistic logic it is not true that $\neg \neg P(x)$ is always equivalent to $P(x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an intuitionistic tautology.  To see this, consider the Kripke frame where:

- $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of functions from a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{ 0, 1 \}$, ordered by inclusion (as subsets of $\mathbb{N} \times \{ 0, 1 \}$; or equivalently, we say $f \le g$ if and only if $\operatorname{dom}(f) \subseteq \operatorname{dom}(g)$ and $g |_{\operatorname{dom}(f)} = f$).
- The universe of discourse is the presheaf $K$ where $K(f) = \mathbb{N}$ for all $f$.
- $P$ is the predicate defined such that $f \Vdash P(n)$ if and only if $(n, 1) \in f$ (or equivalently, $n \in \operatorname{dom}(f)$ and $f(n) = 1$).

Then for this setup, we can verify:

- $f \Vdash \lnot P(n)$ if and only if $n \in \operatorname{dom}(f)$ and $f(n) = 0$.
- $f \Vdash \lnot\lnot P(n)$ if and only if $n \in \operatorname{dom}(f)$ and $f(n) = 1$.
- Therefore, $f \Vdash \lnot P(n) \lor \lnot\lnot P(n)$ if and only if $n \in \operatorname{dom}(f)$.
- It follows that for all $f$, $f \not\Vdash \forall n (\lnot P(n) \lor \lnot\lnot P(n))$, since for any $f\in \mathbb{P}$, its domain is not all of $\mathbb{N}$.
- Therefore, for all $f$, $f \Vdash \lnot \forall n (\lnot P(n) \lor \lnot\lnot P(n))$.
- Thus, for example for the empty function $\emptyset$, $\emptyset \not\Vdash \lnot\lnot \forall n (\lnot P(n) \lor \lnot\lnot P(n))$.

This then shows that $\lnot\lnot \forall x (\lnot P(n) \lor \lnot\lnot P(n))$ cannot be provable in intuitionistic logic.